# ffmpeg - image with zoom - looks low resolution

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm trying to take an image, and apply a slow 'zoom' to the image (think Ken Burns). The animation looks correct, but the image looks extremely low resolution (when the original image is a 5k still). Why is this? Command below:

```
ffmpeg -loop 1 -f image2 -i 'IMG_8444_edit.jpg' -vf "zoompan=z='zoom+0.001" -c:v libx264 -preset fast -t 5 -crf 22 -s 1920x1080 -y 'zoomout.mp4'
```

Comment: Do you have a sample of the problem that you can post?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`zoompan`, by default, scales output to 1280x720 (and at 25 fps).

Use

```
ffmpeg -loop 1 -f image2 -i 'IMG_8444_edit.jpg' -vf "zoompan=z='zoom+0.001:s=WxH,scale=hd1080" -c:v libx264 -preset fast -t 5 -crf 22 -y 'zoomout.mp4'
```

where WxH is your required output resolution from the filter.

Comment: Yes awesome! That was the trick! Question: it looks like the pan zoom filter has some other parameters such as input resolution... If I set that to the size of the still image, would that increase the output quality even further?

Comment: No, you can use the input width and height in expressions, but zoompan will work with the original resolution before it resizes.